# Counting multiple columns based on datetable - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

With a table of dates, I'm trying to count different columns based on weeks.
I manage to do it with one column, and it works fine. But when I'm counting multiple columns I get either wrong or duplicated results. I think it's because of the join.

This works for one column as expected:

```
 SELECT
 DATE_FORMAT(thedate, '%u') as week
,COUNT(t.completed_date) as completed

FROM datetable
LEFT JOIN projects t ON t.completed_date = thedate
WHERE thedate BETWEEN YEAR(NOW()) AND NOW()
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(thedate,7)
```

By adding `,COUNT(t.sales_date) as sales` to the select, I will get duplicated counts for completed and sales.

**Based to this sample (projects)**

```
| id | completed_date | sales_date |
| 1  | NULL           | NULL       |
| 2  | NULL           | 2013-08-26 |
| 3  | NULL           | 2013-08-28 |
| 4  | 2013-09-06     | NULL       |
```

**I'm looking for**

```
| week | completed | sales |
| 34   | 0         | 0     |
| 35   | 0         | 2     |
| 36   | 1         | 0     |
```

I'm using a datetable because I need all dates with 0 when there's no dates.
I think I could solve it by subqueries, but there's 12 other date fields i need to count in this query as well (excluded from the sample).

Is there a better way of solving this than by using lots of subqueries? My SQL is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use subqueries that group each value by week, then join them all together.

```
SELECT d.week, completed, sales
FROM (SELECT YEARWEEK(thedate) week
      FROM datetable
      WHERE thedate BETWEEN YEAR(NOW()) AND NOW()
      GROUP BY week) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEARWEEK(completed_date) week, COUNT(*) completed
           FROM projects
           WHERE completed_date BETWEEN YEAR(NOW()) AND NOW()
           GROUP BY week) c
ON c.week = d.week
LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEARWEEK(sales_date) week, COUNT(*) sales
           FROM projects
           WHERE sales_date BETWEEN YEAR(NOW()) AND NOW()
           GROUP BY week) s
ON s.week = d.week
```

This way is more easily extended to additional columns:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(thedate, '%u') AS week,
       IFNULL(SUM(completed_date = thedate), 0) AS completed,
       IFNULL(SUM(sales_date = thedate), 0) AS sales
FROM datetable
LEFT JOIN projects
ON thedate IN (completed_date, sales_date)
WHERE thedate BETWEEN YEAR(NOW()) AND NOW()
GROUP BY week
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated; when I add 12 more subqueries I'm thinking that there must be an easier way.

Comment: Added a new query, is it better?

Comment: It's much nicer, but really slow even when I add a WHERE clause. It returns 10 rows in 1 second. I might just create the first query with a loop and use that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second query can't make very effective use of indexes, because it's matching `thedate` against multiple columns in `projects`.

Comment: I understand, I'll stick with the subqueries for now then, thanks!